# set minimum primary key for saving django models in database

Tags: django, django-models, primary-key, postgresql-9.2

I am new to Django.I have two models, `Model A` and a new `Model B`

```
class A:
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
```

I have to migrate all the data from **A to B** in such that a way that **primary key of a entry in Model A will be same in Model B**. i.e

`b.id = a.id` where a and b are instance of A and B respectively.

but after this when i **save a new instance the id generated is 5L, 6L** etc. instead of incrementing the prmiary key of the last object created. Is there any way to fix this ??
I am using django 1.3 with postgresql 9.2.

Comment: why don't you use sql dump data from table A to B.

Comment: You need to do this in the database, by setting the relevant sequence. I don't know enough about Postgres to give a proper answer, but it'll be in the documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-altersequence.html looks promising).

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: Thank you. It did it at my db shell.

Comment: @AnshJ : i am no sql expert so dont know how to implement through your above mentioned technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy data from table A into B using insert command 
for example :

```
INSERT INTO A (id, firstname, email) SELECT b.id, b.firstname, b.email FROM B b;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This works fine.... 1 more thing i would like to ask... Model A has been a foreign key to some models(like G,H, J). can i replace A with B.

Comment: Their is one similar question on stackover flow for this (to update forignkey constraint) have a look into it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073706/how-to-alter-a-mysql-tables-foreign-key-using-the-command-line